# Portable function to remove element from DOM when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, popup

I have some `jQuery` "popups" and I'm aware that you can apply `onClick` events to objects at run-time, like so:

```
$('.popup').on('click', 'img.close', function() {
    // Remove the popup
});
```

However, I'm unsure of how to distinguish which popup is being closed based on the click rather than closing them all. Would I have to pass the `this` keyword as a parameter?

Basically all popups that are added to the document consist of this boilerplate code:

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="toolbar">
        Popup Title Here
        <img src="close.png" class="close"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="text">Popup content/data here<p>
</div>
```

I would like to leave the markup as this and control the `onClick` events and which popup to close inside a function that loads at run-time. Is this possible?

Currently I'm assigning an `ID` to every popup and removing them based on the popup's `ID` but this method seems redundant and I'm hoping there is a cleaner approach to handling this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find out the parent `.popup` element of the clicked `close` element

```
$('.popup').on('click', 'img.close', function() {
    $(this).closest('.popup').remove(); //or .hide() if you just want to hide the popup
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, I was unaware of the .closest() function.